# Controls do not fit to form resizing WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, dock

I'm trying to create an app responsive, all the effort I'm putting is not giving me results on the new standard WPF.
  I would make sure to resize the application controls when the form is shrunken or expanded.
As you can see from the pictures item 3 is not completely visible when the form is shrunken and as a result does not fit the new dimension given by the user.
How do I create an application that can automatically adjust the controls? On the normal form I had no problem doing this, but in WPF does not really understand how to adapt automatically, despite having read numerous tutorials. Thank you.

**CODE:**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="SpanCore.MainWindow"
    Title="SpanCore" Height="522" Width="783" MinWidth="400" MinHeight="522">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />SpanCoreSpanCore
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Menu Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFF0EDED" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <MenuItem ToolTip="File" Header="File">
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <DataGrid HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10,26,10,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="h" CanUserResize="False" MinWidth="100" Width="150"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="a" CanUserResize="False" MinWidth="100" Width="150"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="auto" Height="auto">
        <TabItem Header="tab1">
            <Canvas>
                <DockPanel>
                    <GroupBox Header="item1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="168" Width="300">
                        <DataGrid>
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="S"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="P"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="V"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="P"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Pa"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="G"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </GroupBox>
                    <GroupBox Header="item2" Canvas.Left="303" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="168" >
                        <DataGrid>
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Book" MinWidth="80"/>

                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </GroupBox>
                    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <GroupBox Header="item3" Canvas.Left="903" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="202" Height="168" DockPanel.Dock="Right" >
                            <Grid>
                                <RadioButton Content="1t" HorizontalAlignment="left" DockPanel.Dock="left"/>
                                <RadioButton Content="2t" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </GroupBox>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DockPanel>
            </Canvas>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="tab2">
        </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

**IMAGE EXAMPLE:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Dont use `Canvas`, because it is WPF, not Windows Forms.

Comment: Okay, I've removed the Canvas component. The problem now is that item1 and item2 remain anchored to the left when the form is resized, this is good but I want that this control must be enlarge their dimension when I expand the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFDevelopement.SampleWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="SampleWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <Menu Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFF0EDED" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                <MenuItem ToolTip="File" Header="File">
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <DataGrid HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10,26,10,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="h" CanUserResize="False" MinWidth="100" Width="150"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="a" CanUserResize="False" MinWidth="100" Width="150"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="auto" Height="auto">
            <TabItem Header="tab1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Header="item1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="300">
                        <DataGrid>
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="S"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="P"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="V"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="P"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Pa"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="G"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </GroupBox>
                    <GroupBox Grid.Column="1" Header="item2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <DataGrid>
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Book" MinWidth="80" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </GroupBox>
                    <GroupBox Grid.Column="2" Header="item3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <RadioButton Content="1t" />
                            <RadioButton Content="2t" Margin="8,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </GroupBox>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="tab2">
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot]

*And final comment for all WPF programmers: don't use `Canvas` and avoid hardcoded `Width`, `Height` and other such properties. Use Grid instead with proprotional or Auto columns.*

Comment: Okay is a good solution. What can be done to those radio buttons too far from each other (1t and 2t)?

Comment: Remove `HorizontalAlignment` properties or copy updated sample.

Comment: Okay thank you. I have one last question for you: when the window is maximized, item3 outgrows attached properly to the edge of the right, while the other controls item1 and item2 are not resized in landscape mode. I get so disproportionate controls, why does this happen?

Comment: You can play with `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>` like I does in last update: `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions><ColumnDefinition Width="2*" /><ColumnDefinition Width="*" /><ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" /></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>`